# Execution of adding SQL code is not happening in Qt

Tags: c++, sql, qt

When I try to add data to data base through `INSERT INTO`, it isn't adding the data. The database is connected but the execution is not happening

Same database is connected on another window, I tried to disconnected it and then connect it on new page this still shows the same error

```
void signup::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    sql = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE","SQLITE");
    sql.setDatabaseName("/E:/OOP Project/casinousers.db");
    if(sql.open()) {
       qDebug() << "Database connected";
    }
    else {
      qDebug() << "Error in connecting";
    }
    QString email,pass,name;
    int amount;
    email  = ui->lineEdit->text();
    pass = ui->lineEdit_2->text();
    name = ui->lineEdit_3->text();
    amount = ui->lineEdit_4->text().toInt();
    QSqlQuery *query = new QSqlQuery(sql);
    query->prepare("INSERT INTO Data(Email,Password,name,Amount)" "VALUES(':email',':pass',':name',:amount)");
    query->bindValue(":email",email);
    query->bindValue(":pass",pass);
    query->bindValue(":name",name);
    query->bindValue(":amount",amount);
    if(!query->exec()) {
        qDebug() <<" error";
    }
}
```

The output is "error" - it's not adding the data

Comment: NOTE: I have not used Qt, but went to the documentation. Perhaps instead of just printing "error" you could use `querry->lastError()` to retrieve the error message and print that out?

Comment: Thank you Chris, the problem is solved because the DB was locked. :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The database was locked.

I unlocked it and this solved the problem.

I came to know about this problem by printing the actual error

```
qDebug() << query->lastError();
```